# variable initialisation node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

here's my problem in this function I'm trying to return an array of objects. When i do a console.log in the forEach loop as you can see the array is filled but when I try to print it juste before my return statement it's empty.
[image]

[image]

and here's my full js file :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Maths = require("../Utils/Maths");
const Stop = require("../Commands/stop");
const EventMitter = require("events");
const emitter = new EventMitter();
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports.play = async(client, channel, players) => {
    players.push(client.guilds.cache.first().members.cache.array().filter(mem => mem.user.username === "user1").map(mem => mem.user)[0]);
    players.push(client.guilds.cache.first().members.cache.array().filter(mem => mem.user.username === "users2").map(mem => mem.user)[0]);

    try {
        await beginMessage(players, channel);

        let playersCards = await beginGame(client, players);
        console.log(playersCards);

        emitter.on("stop", async () => {
            await channel.delete();
            console.log("jeu fini");
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }    
};

async function beginMessage(players, channel) {
    let message = "que le jeu commence ";
    players.forEach(player => {
        message += `${player.toString()} `;
    });

    await channel.send(message);
}

async function beginGame(client, players) {
    let playersCards = [];

    fs.readFile("Utils/cartes.json", 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        let cartes = JSON.parse(data);
        cartes = cartes.cartes;

        players.forEach(async player => {
            let playerCards = await distributeCards(player, cartes);
            playersCards.push(playerCards);
            //console.log(playersCards);
        });

        console.log(playersCards);
        return playersCards;
    });
}

async function distributeCards(player, cartes) {
    let playerCards = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        let carte = cartes[Maths.getRandomNumber(0,12)];
        carte.count--;
        playerCards.push(carte.name);
    }

    let dmChannel = await player.createDM();
    await dmChannel.send(playerCards);

    return playerCards;
}

module.exports.finishGame = function (client) {
    emitter.emit("stop");
};
```

Must be a initialisation mistake or something like that I've been searching in my code but can't find it.

Comment: You don't have to paste the screenshot of your code. Only pasted code should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 3:

Since `fs.readFile` is not async we need to convert it to a promised based function something like below.

```
function readFile(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

I have updated the codesandbox snippet. Please check and see it that solves your issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nodejs-async-foreach-promise-v16w6

EDIT 2:

You need to implement custom forEach that will execute and return values as async. Something like this:

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

I have written a codesandbox snippet that might help you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nodejs-async-foreach-promise-v16w6

EDIT:

Since you are using promise inside the forEach loop, the values are pushed 
 only after the promise is resolved. Since forEach is completes even before the values are pushed to `playersCards` you will not be able to see any values.

You can do something like this. I have updated the code. Haven't tested the code, but can help if there is issue.

```
async fs.readFile("Utils/cartes.json", 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);

    let cartes = JSON.parse(data);
    cartes = cartes.cartes;

    await players.forEach(async player => {
        let playerCardsPromiseValue = await distributeCards(player, cartes);
        playersCards.push(playerCardsPromiseValue);
        //console.log(playersCards);
    });

    console.log(playersCards);
    return playersCards;
});
```

Comment: it wasn't the first one is "playersCards" with a "s" and the second one "playerCards"

Comment: @andrc I have updated my answer. Haven't tested the code, but can check if there is any issue

Comment: thank's a lot but now I've got an other problem at the begining of the code at those lines : 
let playersCards = await beginGame(client,players);
console.log(playersCards);
playersCards is undefine as if my beginGame function was not an async function

Comment: await can't be used that way. you can use it only inside an async function

Comment: You can do something like this ```(async () => {
  let playersCards = await beginGame(client,players);
  console.log(playersCards);
})();```

Comment: or you can do use `.then()` to resolve the promise and execute things inside of that.
```
let playersCards = []
beginGame(client,players).then(data => {
  playersCards = data
});
```

Comment: My method called "play" is already declared with the async keyword : module.exports.play = async(client, channel, players)

Comment: I have made edit to my answer. hopefully it should work now.